# Is it possible to enable x-forward for in AWS Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have a ALB (Application Load Balancer) setup in my `aws` account. And it is being directed to some application running in `fargate` everything works fine.

But if I see the application logs, it shows the Load Balancer IP. But I need to get the Source IP. Is this something I have to configure at Load Balancer or from application level?

I read [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/x-forwarded-headers.html#x-forwarded-for) `aws` documentation and it doesn't provide a comprehensive way of setting this `X-Forward For` feature.

Comment: They should work out of the box. Maybe your app logs don't show full request?

Comment: Are you suggesting, this header is being set by default?

Comment: Yes, it should always be included by default, with no way of disabling.

Comment: Is there a way I can confirm this?